# Ubuntu Plesk SSH issues (permitRootLogin)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, migration, plesk

I got a new Ubuntu 14.04 server with unlimited Plesk delivered and working. If I try to migrate the old server through Plesk's Migration Manager it reports the following issues:

```
rsync execution error: Unknown error (255).
Stderr is:
--------------------------------
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 55: Bad configuration option: permitrootlogin
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(226) [Receiver=3.1.0]

--------------------------------
```

/etc/ssh/ssh_config (line 55 on destination server):

```
PermitRootLogin yes
```

/etc/ssh/sshd_config (also on Destination server):

```
#PermitRootLogin without-password
PermitRootLogin yes
```

Both Plesk's are the same (12.0.18), originating server is Ubuntu 12.04LTS Destination server is Ubuntu 14.04LTS.

Answer (score 8):

**TL;DR** The line `PermitRootLogin yes` does not belong in the `ssh_config` file, only in the `sshd_config` file.

The file `ssh_config` describes the configuration options for the client. As the error logs say, there is no such option `PermitRootLogin` for the client. The `sshd_config` file however, describes the options for the daemon. (You can recognise this because of ssh**d**) The server/daemon does have a `PermitRootLogin` option, so it belongs there.

Comment: I agree. But if I remove PermitRootLogin from ssh_config and then use the Migration Manager in Plesk it crashes Plesk and ultimately the whole server because the memory of the server is eventually full. This freshley delivered server came delivered with Plesk and with this parameters. I have a tech looking into it right now but it takes a long time so I think he is puzzled too. :-)